# Supervisor config and certain python files

Tags: python, bash

I need to start on boot and monitoring a python script with supervisor.
The python script works when starting manually by sudo python getdata.py

My scripy getdata.py executes  subprocess.call(['bash','jpgdwn.sh'])
This file also executes commands with sudo right.
I think there could be a problem maybe why supervisor isn't working with that?

I added a 2nd file (led.py - which blinks a led) to the supervisord.conf to test if supervisor is working and it is.

What do I have to do that getdata.py is also properly executed?

```
    GNU nano 2.7.4           Datei: /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf                                        

; supervisor config file

[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

; The [include] section can just contain the "files" setting.  This
; setting can list multiple files (separated by whitespace or
; newlines).  It can also contain wildcards.  The filenames are
; interpreted as relative to this file.  Included files *cannot*
; include files themselves.

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf

[program:getdata]
command=python /home/pi/bsc_arduino2.py
user=pi
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs = 5
startretries=3
stdout_logfile=/home/pi/getdata.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=5MB
stopsignal=INT
stopwaitsecs=5

[program:led]
command=python /home/pi/led.py
user=pi
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs = 5
startretries=3
stdout_logfile=/home/pi/getdata.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=5MB
stopsignal=INT
stopwaitsecs=5
```